# Why Wild Cards can't be used in generic class & method declaration?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-construction, jvm, bounded-wildcard

Declaration like this :

```
  class A<X extends Number & List> {  }
```

is allowed.Whereas declaration like this is not allowed.

```
  class A<? extends Number & List> {  }
```

Is there any logical explanation about why Java restricts us to do that?

& what's the actual difference between

```
      <T extends Number>  
     & <? extends Number>?
```

Comment: Do you actually have a class that extends `Number` and implements `List`?  Or does it extend `Number` and implement `List<Number>`?  or does X extend `Number` and implement `List<X>`?  How would you even write that last one without declaring the type `X` somewhere?

Comment: Good point -- `Number` and `List` aren't really types you'd expect to coexist like that.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Even if they do coexist like that, I was just pointing out that you might need the generic definition to specify what your list is holding.  Either way, it is probably better to avoid the raw type.

Comment: @PaulHanbury: They are tested & compiled successfully.Number & List are taken just for example.You can replace them with any custom class name,interface name.The point here is why wild card is not allowed in generic class/method declaration.

Comment: @DebadyutiMaiti:  By your logic, I should be happy with the following code because it compiles and passes its tests:  `public class Math {public static int multiply(int x,int y){int p = 0;for(int i=0;i<x;i++) for(int j=0;j<y;j++)p++;return p;}}`  I am not happy with it.  Similarly, I don't think that using raw lists are a good idea either... especially in a templated class.

Comment: @DebadyutiMaiti: My point, however was that you need to explicitly name your type (i.e., "X", not "?") so that you can refer to it within the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of a type parameter like `T` is so that you can use it as a type inside the class. What would a wildcard there even mean? If you can't use it anywhere, why have a type parameter at all?

Answer (score 3):

If you used `<? extends Number & List>`, then you wouldn't be able to *do* anything with the type parameter.  It'd be completely useless.

Similarly, `? extends Number` lets you deal with the special case when you don't need to refer to the type that extends number, and you don't need to give it a name.

Answer (score 0):

Generic class and interface declarations want type parameters, such as T or U. ? is a wildcard, better used for method parameters that are themselves generic:

```
class Foo<T extends Number & List> {
    void doStuff(List<T> items) {
        // ...
    }

    void doMoreStuff(List<? extends OutputStream> streams) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

doStuff() indicates that it wants to operate on a `List<T>` where T is the type parameter on class Foo. So:

```
class Weird extends Number implements List {
    //
}

Foo<Weird> f = new Foo<Weird>();
f.doStuff(...);   // wants a List<Weird>
```

If we called doMoreStuff() on f, we could hand it something of type `List<OutputStream>`, `List<FilterOutputStream>`, `List<ByteArrayOutputStream>`, etc.

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `doStuff()` on Foo, not weird?