# java Generic wildcard "?"

Tags: java, generics

I referred to documentation on Java Generics, and trying to use the wildcard "?" in a simple program:

```
class Unknown <?> {

}

public class UnknownTypes {

    public static void main(String s[] ) {

    }
}
```

Wildcard "?" refers to an Unknown type, so in class Unknown, I used type-parameter wildcard itself; however when I compile I get compilation error. If I had used like this it would have worked.

```
class Unknown <T> {

}
```

If wildcard "?" refers to unknown type, why can't we use "?" as type parameter.

The following is the compile error that I get.

```
UnknownTypes.java:1: error: <identifier> expected
class Unknown <?> {
           ^
UnknownTypes.java:1: error: '{' expected
class Unknown <?> {
            ^
UnknownTypes.java:10: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
```

Is wildcard "?" used in conjunction with something else?

Comment: Unknown in the sense that it will never be known. The wildcard doesn't make sense in a class declaration because when you instantiate the class, you'll parameterize it with a type. It's more useful for things like `List<?> list = nonGenericGetList();` (you'll do this a lot when working with old libraries).

Comment: What are you trying to solve with an unknown type here?

Comment: To illustrate David's statement, imagine how you will use the parameter had you are allowed to use ?. For instance, a class member declaration such as `private ? a` would be legal, which is neither allowed nor make sense.

Comment: see exactly same question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914302/why-wild-cards-cant-be-used-in-generic-class-method-declaration

Answer (score 3):

You can't *name* a generic parameter as `?`, because `?` is not a valid identifier - a valid name of a variable. You have to give a generic parameter a valid java name so you can refer to it in the implementation.

You can only specify `?` as a generic bound:

```
List<?> list; // a variable holding a reference to a list of unknown type
```

You can't use `?` when creating an instance:

```
new ArrayList<?>(); // can't do this
```

or as a parameter name of a class :

```
class MyClass<?> { // can't do this
```

Answer (score 3):

To define a generic class with a type parameter, you cannot use a wildcard (in the generic class it is a type)

```
class Unknown <TYPE> {
  TYPE foo; // <-- specifies the type of foo.
}
```

When using it, you can use the wildcard

```
Unknown<?> some = new Unknown<String>(); // <-- some is any kind of Unknown.
```

Answer (score 2):

You only use the wildcard when referring to an instance of a class. Not in the class declaration.

```
class Unknown<T>{}

Unknown<?> instance= new Unknown<Integer>();


public void canHandleAnyUnknown(Unknown<?> wild){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard means 'anything' not unknown. You can use only Alphabets as type parameter.